# Wordpress register_activation_hook() + global variables + class: cannot redeclare

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing my first wordpress plugin and I'm trying to create a function to be called when the plugin is activated.

Currently it looks like this:

```php
class ThumbsUp {

...

}

global $thumbs;
function thumbs_install() {
    //global $thumbs;
    $thumbs = new ThumbsUp();    /* Line 160 */
    $thumbs->installThumbsUp();
}                                /* Line 162 */

// When plugin is activated -> install.
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'thumbs_install');
```

But when I activate the plugin I get the following error:

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
>
> **Fatal error**: Cannot redeclare `thumbs_install()` (previously declared in `/dev/site/wp-content/plugins/thumbs-up/thumbs-up.php:160`) in `/dev/site/wp-content/plugins/thumbs-up/thumbs-up.php` on line 162

I've googled and looked and it's talked about as a variable scope issue but I can't find any examples of the answer and my php is not strong enough to translate the discussion into code.

Here's [the solution described by John Blackbourn](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2008-December/022934.html) in the [WP-hackers ML](http://lists.automattic.com/mailman/listinfo/wp-hackers):

> Any global variables that you want to reference inside the function that is called by `register_activation_hook()` must be explicitly declared as global inside the main body of the plugin (ie. *outside* of this function). The plugin file is `include()`-ed inside another function at the point where it is activated unlike at others times when the plugin file is simply `include()`-ed. Phew. Bit of an odd one to get your head around but there we go.

I thought I had done what is described but I still get the error.  I've also tried every other combination of where I could possibly put the global `$thumbs`...

Comment: Could you please mark the lines 160 and 162 of the file /dev/site/wp-content/plugins/thumbs-up/thumbs-up.php in the code snippet?

Comment: Have added the line numbers to the appropriate lines.

Comment: Nevermind I was looking at completely the wrong thing..

Comment: maybe you could answer yourself and accept that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more generic answer to this question: every error that occurs in the code that is run from the function registered with `register_activation_hook` will be shown as "`cannot redeclare ...` " instead of the actual error. I suspect this is because of the way WordPress includes the plugin file when it calls the activation hook.

Comment: This answer is wrong and misleading. Errors happening from within the code of the callback function passed as a parameter to `register_activation_hook` will show as what they are, not as a *cannot re-declare ...* error. The re-declaration error happens when a name is re-declared in a scope where it already exists. This is also what happens here.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: if you arrived here via your search engine for a result about Wordpress's `register_activation_hook()` and `global` variables, please jump to the second part of this answer.*

---

The rationale behind this error message is that the `thumbs_install` name is first created while `include()`ed once, and then a second time.

One of those times, it is `include()`ed in the scope of `activate_plugin()` from [`/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` on line 560](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1244eaff8fb2ab31294c8b10ec75a2f9744c3668/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L560); the other one is most likely your doing: Wordpress does not include any plugin that is not yet activated and includes the plugin file in `activate_plugin()` only once.

Moreover, I was unable to reproduce the issue with the code you pasted in your question, but I got exactly that error with the following version of the `ThumbsUp` class:

```php
class ThumbsUp {
    function installThumbsUp() {
        include(__FILE__);
    }
}
```

However, since you did not share the code of your `ThumbsUp` class with us, I cannot help you further on that direct matter.

It is worth noting that the *first* (before activation) inclusion of the plugin in the `activate_plugin()` function is aimed at preventing Wordpress from crashing because of un-activated plugins; and therefore, it is very well possible that the extra `include()` or `require()` happens somewhere else in the code of your plugin (not necessarily in a local scope).

---

About the use of `global` variables in the callback function passed to `register_activation_hook()`; essentially because the first `include()` (during activation) of the plugin happens in the *scope of a function* ([`activate_plugin()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1244eaff8fb2ab31294c8b10ec75a2f9744c3668/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L560)), it is necessary to declare those variables `global` in every location of the plugin where they are accessed.

That means: **they need to be explicitly set `global` in the scope of the plugin file too** (where you normally consider variables to already be global).

This is because the said variables are defined, during the first activation, *in the scope of `activate_plugin()`*, and *unless set global explicitly, they will not exist in the global scope*.

Example:

```
<?php
global $myvar;
$myvar = 'some value';

function using_myvar() {
    global $myvar;
    some_processing_with($myvar);
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'using_myvar');
```

*Nota bene: Since after the first activation, the plugin is considered 'safe' to be `include()`ed globally; it is only necessary for variables used by the aforementioned callback to be declared global in the file scope.*